# What is the variable that contains the source file name?

Tags: external-files, auxiliary-files, jobname

I am writing a package that saves information to an external file. I would like to name that file according to the source one; something like
 foo.tex -> foo.bar
But I cannot find any variable that contains 'foo'. I am pretty sure that there must be one because the table of contents is saved to foo.toc.

Any pointers?

Comment: For this purpose `\jobname` is always the right way to go. If you want to get the real main file name, which can be different from the job name if it is changed using the `-jobname` compiler argument, then see [Macro to retrieve the real name of the source file if pdflatex is invoked with -jobname](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54894/2975)

Comment: since 2020 there are standard macros , documented in
https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex-dev/base/ltfilehook-doc.pdf

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You want the macro `\jobname`.  This isn't quite the filename; to quote from the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-filename):

> TeX retains what it considers the name of the job, only, in the primitive `\jobname`; this is the name of the file first handed to TeX, stripped of its directory name and of any extension (such as `.tex`). If no file was passed (i.e., you're using TeX interactively), `\jobname` has the value `texput` (the name that's given to `.log` files in this case).

So if you're processing `foo.tex`, `\jobname` will be `foo` (which, of course, is probably what you want anyway).

Comment: Curiously, TeX does retain the current line number, see `inputlineno`

Comment: This is correct. Nevertheless, if you _input_ a tex file into another, `\jobname` will hold the name of the file which is importing the other file.

Answer (score 10):

You are looking for `\jobname`.

EDIT: To add some value to my answer - pages 288-289 of the [LaTeX2e sources](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) contain the definition of `\@starttoc`, the command that reads/writes ToC data from/to external files. This definition reveals the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It is always nice to have good sources.

Answer (score 9):

```
\usepackage{currfile}
Filename: \currfilename
```

Comment: My use case was that I had a large main file with several other tex files included - this is what I needed! (the other suggestion gives only the "main.tex" file where I include the other .tex files.

Answer (score 1):

In LuaTeX, the equivalent of `\jobname` on the lua side is `tex.jobname`.
In LaTeX3 we have

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\jobname\\
\ExplSyntaxOn
\g_file_curr_dir_str/
\g_file_curr_name_str.
\g_file_curr_ext_str
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Some use case may benefit from the recent `ltfilehook` package which is built into LaTeX, one has `\CurrentFile`, `\CurrentFilePath`... available in the hook instructions.