# Macro to retrieve the real name of the source file if pdflatex is invoked with -jobname

Tags: file-lookup, jobname

> **This question led to a new feature in a package:**
>   As of version 0.6 [`currfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/currfile) supports the requested feature via a new package option and the `-recorder` compiler switch. For details, see [Martin's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54894/3751) below.

From the documentation I assumed that Martin Scharrer's [`currfile`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/currfile) package would do this. However, while it deals well with tracking the actual file name over `\input`s and `\include`s, the name of the main `.tex` file is still set to `\jobname`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile}

\begin{document}
  I was compiled as job \texttt{\jobname} from the file \texttt{\currfilename}.
\end{document}
```

If saved as `test.tex` and compiled with `pdflatex -jobname bla test.tex` the output is:

[image]

Even compiling with `pdflatex -jobname bla "\input{test.tex}"` does not change the output.

Comment: Yep, `currfile` uses `\jobname` for the main file. I'm not aware of any other way to find out the real file name (or even its extension), but I'm happy to learn about one if it exists. This is actually a recent feature request for the package.

Comment: I now figured a way out while answering the question [Full path of current file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42417/2975). The feature there can also be used for the main file name. I posted an answer showing this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the call

```
pdflatex -jobname bla "\RequirePackage{currfile}\input{test}"
```

the macro `\currfilename` prints `test.tex`

One has to change the meaning of `\input` (actually of `\@iinput`) before executing it.

Comment: Neat trick! Actually I have been thinking the same direction, but tried with `\usepackage`, which doesn't work before the `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 13):

You were right that my [`currfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/currfile) package 
should give you the real file name, but there is no way to read the real main file name from TeX directly. Therefore I had to use `\jobname`.

However, I now found a way to do this by reading the `\jobname.fls` file produced by the `-recorder` compiler switch.
This functionality is available since v0.6 from 2012/05/06.
Note that `-recorder` is already used by `latexmk`, so if you are using it there is no extra effort.

To enable this simply load `currfile` with the `realmainfile` option. The related `abspath` option, which gives you absolute paths for all input files, will also enable `realmainfile`.

```
% Compile with: (pdf|xe|lua|)latex -recorder filename
% Needs two runs with MiKTeX, one with TeX Live
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}[2012/05/06]

\begin{document}

Jobname: \jobname

Main file (path): \currfilepath

\end{document}
```

If you don't need the full functionality of `currfile` (which will update several macros for every input file), then you can use the sub-package `currfile-abspath` directly:

```
% Compile with: (pdf|xe|lua|)latex -recorder filename
% Needs two runs with MiKTeX, one with TeX Live
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{currfile-abspath}

\getmainfile % In preamble or body

\begin{document}

Jobname: \jobname

Main file: \themainfile

\end{document}
```

Comment: Martin, this is way cool! I have edited the package update into the question.

Comment: @Daniel: Good stuff. Note that your original MWE still requires the `realmainfile` option in order to work, and `-recorder` to be used at least once of course.

Comment: what about the case when there is an underscore character in the filename (e.g. file_Chapter_001.tex)?

Comment: @reckoner: In `currfile` all characters in filenames are handled using the category code "other", so underscores work and will not be taken as the math subscript operator. However, usually you need to use a proper font (like `tt`) to get them typeset correctly.

Comment: Also note that if you initially compile it with `-recorder` then recompile without `-recorder` then it still work without any warning (and mostly guaranteed to give the correct result because the .fls file is always placed in the output directory)