# What is the correct way to delineate directories in Lua?

Tags: luatex, best-practices, lua

I have been experimenting with some Lua code to list directories and provide them to the TeX engine.

I have been using the `Lua File System (lfs)` module.

The first part list the current directory (code line 4) and it is printed using `\`, as `C:\Users\Admin\...`

In the second part I iterate over the directory which I am providing as a variable,

```
`local z="C:/test"`
```

This also works if I provide it as: `local z="C:\test"

The library accepts this as a valid directory. I am curious to find out how well this will work on other operating systems (I have tested on Windows) and what is the best practice in this regard.

[image]

Full MWE listing follows. (Warning it can print 100s of pages if you test on `C:` alone, create a small temporary directory to test).

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]TeX, [primitive]TeX}
\usepackage{luacode} % loads luatexbase as well
% Emphasis
%\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}            % prefer old tt font
\newcommand\emphasis[2][blue]{\lstset{emph={exec,if,then,else,do,end,while,for,print,sprint,directlua,#2},
   emphstyle={\ttfamily\textcolor{#1}}}}%

\lstset{language={[LaTeX]TeX},
      escapeinside={{(*@}{@*)}}, 
      numbers=left, 
      gobble=0,
      stepnumber=1,numbersep=5pt, 
       numberstyle={\footnotesize\color{gray}},%firstnumber=last,
      breaklines=true,
      framesep=5pt,
      basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
      showstringspaces=false,
      keywordstyle=\ttfamily\textcolor{blue},
      stringstyle=\color{orange},
      commentstyle=\color{black},
      rulecolor=\color{gray!10},
      breakatwhitespace=true,
     showspaces=false,  % shows spacing symbol
     xleftmargin=0pt,
     xrightmargin=5pt,
     aboveskip=3pt, % compact the code looks ugly in type
     belowskip=7pt,  % user responsible to insert any skips
      backgroundcolor=\color{gray!15}}
\begin{document}

%\begin{tcblisting}{} uncomment if you have the latest version of tcolorbox
\begin{luacode}
  require "lfs"
  local temp=lfs.currentdir()
  tex.sprint(-2, temp)
  tex.sprint("\\par")
  function attrdir (path)
    for file in lfs.dir(path) do
        if file ~= "." and file ~= ".." then
            local f = path..'/'..file
            tex.sprint (-1, f.."\\par     ")
            local attr = lfs.attributes (f)
            assert (type(attr) == "table")
            if attr.mode == "directory" then
                attrdir (f)
            else
               -- for name, value in pairs(attr) do
                    --tex.sprint (-2,name, value)
                -- end
            end
        end
    end
  end
  local z="C:/test"
  attrdir (z)
\end{luacode}
%\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great question! I've searched about path separator and found an [old thread about it](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-07/msg00091.html) in the `lua-l` mailing list. An entry in the [Lua FAQ reference](http://www.luafaq.org/#T1.40) tells us: "`package.config` is a string where the first 'character' is the directory separator; so `package.config:sub(1,1)` is either a slash or a backslash. As a general rule, try to use this when building paths."

Comment: @PauloCereda Thanks, so what you saying `lfs` has `package.config:sub(1,1)` already incorporated?

Comment: I'm really not sure if `lfs` gets the path separator from `package.config`. `:(` Maybe it relies on `/`, since it seems to work in most of the cases (at least for both Linux and Windows). That would be my guess. `package.config` is a string and the first character contains the path separator. I think it would be more reliable to create a local variable, get the path separator and use it instead of hardcoding it, but `/` might just work fine. `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `/` for path separators on both unix and windows. "google" tells me that windows software also accepts `/` as a separator, but you can't use it on the command line as it denotes an option / command line argument.

Instead of writing `tex.sprint(-1, f.."\\par     ")` you should write `tex.tprint({-2 , f},{"\\par     "})` and you can use `lfs.isdir()` to check for a directory. Otherwise a good solution.

Comment: Thanks. Oops! didn't know about the `tex.tprint` is that in the reference?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides yes, it was added recently (a year ago) ;) - It lets you insert strings with different catcodes into the buffer, very handy for this kind of mixture of pure string and TeX command string.

Answer (score 9):

<sup>I decided to write an answer. `:)`</sup>

In general, portability is very challenging. Usually the best situation is to write code that does not depend on the underlying system. Sadly, there are cases where we need to know  about the bowels of our host. And now comes the tricky part.

Patrick's answer is the way to go. `:)` IMHO using `/` as path separator is generally portable - of course, there are extreme cases where some devices don't even have a hierarchical filesystem, but thankfully it's not our situation here. `:)` If we stick with the Windows/Unix/Linux/BSD/Mac worlds, I think we are safe with `/`.

A potential problem that depends on the underlying system is when we talk about *absolute* paths. Now it's tricky. I'd say to avoid assigning drive letters or filesystem protocols to paths. I'd go with relative paths and try to get stuff done from it.

I've been asking myself if Lua actually has a path separator. It does, as the [Lua Unofficial FAQ](http://www.luafaq.org/#T1.40) tell us:

> `package.config` is a string where the first 'character' is the directory separator; so `package.config:sub(1,1)` is either a slash or a backslash. As a general rule, try to use this when building paths.

I'd stick with `/` for the fun of it. `:)` Still, if we want to rely on the system's path separator, I'd write a function to build paths instead of hardcoding them:

```lua
function getPath(...)
    local pathseparator = package.config:sub(1,1);
    local elements = {...}
    return table.concat(elements, pathseparator)
end
```

If I want to access `foo ► bar ► baz.txt`, you can use `getPath("foo","bar","baz.txt")` which will give you:

```
foo\bar\baz.txt
```

in Windows, or:

```
foo/bar/baz.txt
```

in Unix and friends. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to play with your code on my new shiny desktop

```
$ uname -a
OpenBSD oko.bagdala2.net 5.1 GENERIC.MP#188 i386
```

As you can see I am using version of OpenBSD which will be released 1st of May.

My version of Lua is

```
 $ lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
>
```

My version of TeXLive on this machine is

```
texlive_texmf-full-2011p0
```

which is roughly a stable release from the July of the last year.

I was not sure what you were expecting me to do with the code but

```
$ luatex mama.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2012030705 (rev 4277) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./mama.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {tufte-book}
```

The Lua code itself

```
$ lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require "lfs"
stdin:1: module 'lfs' not found:
        no field package.preload['lfs']
        no file './lfs.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lfs.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lfs/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lfs.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lfs/init.lua'
        no file './lfs.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lfs.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
>
```

By the way your

```
z="C:/test"
```

is totally unportable. I made quick fix but you will have to have some kind of autoconfig to be able to run on various operating systems.

**Edit:**

Thanks for quick inputs! Running **lualatex** with produces output after screaming about

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tcolorbox.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `listings' for package `tcolorbox'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \lstloadlanguages
                     {[LaTeX]TeX, [primitive]TeX}
?
```

but sure enough there is an output. I have not changed **tufte-book** class. The same problem with **tcolorbox.sty** (which is expected) even if I use article class. Do you want me to put somewhere on the server log file or pdf file?

Also using texlua instead of lua just with the portion of lua script gives

```
$ texlua mama.lua
mama.lua:3: attempt to call field 'sprint' (a nil value)
```

I am guessing that this is now more useful?

**New Edit**

After adding tcolorbox.sty into the local directory there was another problem

```
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
! I can't find file `tcblistings.code.tex'.
<to be read again> 
                   \futurelet 
l.299 \tcb@temp

Please type another input file name: 
! I can't find file `tcblistings.code'.
<to be read again> 
                   \futurelet 
l.299 \tcb@temp
```

I downloaded from the Internet and installed `tcblistings.code.tex`

After that lualatex went without a glitch. The pdf file has only one line

```
tcolorbox /home/predrag
```

Which happens not to be the directory from the file (your C:/test)
which I edited to

```
  local z="/home/predrag/Desktop/downloads"
```

However that is the directory in which I had your tex source code, style file and the other required tex file.

I am still not sure what you were trying to do but sure enough after two iterations it "works" on OpenBSD. At this point I could guess that it should work on NetBSD and DragonFly BSD (Note TeXLive is not ported to FreeBSD).

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I am sorry, you need the tufte-class or change to article, sorry I left it there from a document I am writing. You must also check you have `lualibs` which should load `lfs`.

Comment: You should run this through `lualatex`, not `luatex`, as it's a LaTeX document. And: `lua` does not have `lfs` installed. Use `texlua`. Other than that, I am not sure if your answer is really an answer?!?

Comment: You will need the latest version of `tcolorbox` (that is why I had a note in the code). Worth having a look it is a good package.

Comment: With your latest edit: you can't call functions from the _tex_ library in `texlua`.

Comment: @Patrick Gundlach Thanks Patrick. As you could see I am completely ignorant about Lua. Maybe some time in the future I will find some time and motivation to learn something about it. Right now I do not see how I could use for my day work.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac Thanks for persevering and getting it to work.