# How to use 'lfs' library in LuaLaTeX preamble?

Tags: luatex

I need to define absolute path of `.tex` file, and I already learned how to do it:

```
\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir())}/}
```

What I don't know is how to include `lfs` library to my LuaLaTeX preamble. I used LaTeX for the few years, but I don't have not TeX nor Lua programming experience.

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48179/what-is-the-correct-way-to-delineate-directories-in-lua/48187) answer, I saw the code like this:

```
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
  require "lfs"
\end{luacode}
```

I did not tried this code yet, but even it enough to run `\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir())}/}` I need some comments about solution.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir())}/}

\setmainjfont[
    Path          = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont   = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
    BoldFont      = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc
]{nishiki-teki}

\begin{document}
  done
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lfs` library is available out-of-the-box in LuaTeX. As such, you do not need to do anything special: it will 'just work'. A very minimal demo for both plain LuaTeX and LuaLaTeX:

```
\directlua{print(lfs.currentdir())}
\csname @@end\endcsname
\end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Accept and vote-up.