# LaTeX command to pick root directory

Tags: paths

I work on a folder with LaTeX files on two different computers. Dropbox syncs both folders, but the location of folders are different in different computers, so when I include a photo in one computer, it generates error in the other one as the paths are not the same. 
How can I make LaTeX to pick up the current path ?

Comment: If you use relative paths there should be no problem.

Comment: You should use relative paths instead. However, for security reasons relative paths can't include `..` to refer to the parent directory. But you can get the absolute path using the `currfile` package when loaded with the `abspath` option. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42417/2975. Note that this requires the `-recorder` option for the LaTeX compiler (e.g. `pdflatex`).

Comment: define multiple directory? I use   `\graphicspath{{./graph1/}{./graph2/}}` to load from both directories.