# Relative paths for \input and building from different directories

Tags: external-files, input, include, paths

### The minimal example

If I have a directory containing my main LaTeX source file and it uses `\input` to incorporate some data in another file, I can use a relative pathname.  E.g., with these files:

#### ~/tmp/relative-paths-mwe/mwe.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{./src/ex.tex}
\end{document}
```

#### ~/tmp/relative-paths-mwe/src/ex.tex

```
some input
```

Now, from the command line, if I'm in `~/tmp/relative-paths-mwe`, I can build as expected:

```
~/tmp/relative-paths-mwe$ pdflatex mwe.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
...
Output written on mwe.pdf (1 page, 12192 bytes).
Transcript written on mwe.log.
```

However, if I'm in the parent directory, `~/tmp/`, I can't build because the relative paths (as I understand it, and based on the symptoms) are resolved with respect to the current working directory rather than the file where the `\input` appears:

```
~/tmp$ pdflatex relative-paths-mwe/mwe.tex 
...! LaTeX Error: File `./src/ex.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name:
```

Is there a way to specify the paths in such a way that I can refer to other content using relative paths, but still be able to call `pdflatex` from arbitrary directories?

### The non-minimal example

I think that the above is a complete minimal working example for which if I get an answer, I can solve my actual problem.  In case there's a difference that someone can predict in advance, or anyone is wondering *why* I'm trying to do something unusual, a bit of explanation is in order.  I've got a source repository for a project, and it has a subdirectory for a LaTeX document, and a subdirectory for an [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) project.   The document had been using the listings environment to include source code from the Maven project using relative paths along the lines of

```
../mavenproject/src/more-path/code.extension
```

There's a [LaTeX Maven Mojo](http://mojo.codehaus.org/latex-maven-plugin/) that's supposed to be able to compile LaTeX documents, so I decided to try moving the document directory to `mavenproject/src/latex/mydoc`.  Now, I can build the document manually from `mavenproject/src/latex/mydoc` if I change the relative paths to

```
../../more-path/code.extension
```

but I can't build with those paths using the LaTeX Mojo, because it's run from the `mavenproject` directory, which is several directories up from the document root.  I can obviously adjust to handle that, but then I can't build from `mydoc` anymore.  I'm hoping that there's a way to specify the pathnames relative to the including document, or to specify the a document root, and write paths relative to that.  I *hope* that a solution to the minimal example above will transfer over to my actual situation.

Comment: The typical advice for path is to either put all your files into one directory or use `TEXINPUTS`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder all of my latex source is in the same directory, actually. I'm documenting some program code that needs to be in another tree, and that's how this is actually arising. It's not uncommon, from what I've seen, though, to break larger documents into multiple files that reside in various subjects res, and that are referenced by relative path names.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Is it expected, then that relative pathnames in files are resolved against the current working directory of the `pdflatex` (`latex`, etc.) directory, rather than the directory containing the file?  That seems to break the concept of a relative pathname.  Shouldn't we expect `\include{./foo.tex}` in a file `bar.tex` to look for `foo.tex` in the same directory as `bar.tex`?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It's not the current file that processes itself, but the overall `pdflatex` process. If you do a complex C compilation, you can move from a directory to another and use relative paths, but only when compiling one of the `.c` files. Then a linking phase takes place, but there's no analogy with linking in TeX: everything is obtained in a unique run. One could modify `\input` (not `\include`, I'm afraid) to use a path relative to the file it's called from.

Comment: I am lazy, so I put my include file in `$HOME` (only have one include file), since that is searched by default by Latex. Otherwise, as others said, use $TEXINPUTS

Answer (score 10):

Rather than

```
\input{./src/ex.tex}
```

It'd usually better to do

```
\input{ex.tex}
```

then use (from anywhere)

```
TEXINPUTS=$HOME/tmp/relative-paths-mwe//:$TEXINPUTS: pdflatex mwe
```

It isn't really that relative paths are resolved against the current working directory but rather they are resolved against the directories in TEXINPUTS (whether specified as an environment variable or a kpathsea configuration in texmf.cnf file. By ending the path with `//` you allow subdirectories to be searched  so the `ex.tex` will be found in the `src` subdirectory, as well as the `mwe.tex` from the commandline. the trailing `:` in TEXINPUTS ensures that the standard places are also searched for the usual classes and packages.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140895/discussion-on-answer-by-david-carlisle-relative-paths-for-input-and-building-fr).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}  % ← need this package
\begin{document}
\input{\currfileabsdir/src/ex.tex}  % use `\currfileabsdir`
\end{document}
```

How it work should be very obvious. As noted in the `currfile` package documentation you need `-recorder` flag, and you might want to experiment with `\InputIfFileExists` etc. if you use MikTeX (for details why refer to the documentation of that package...)