# How to Access Files Outside of Current Direcory

Tags: graphics, bibliographies

I have a simple question.  How do I access files outside of my current directory in LaTeX?  I have a project that I am updating and saving each day's version in a separate folder.  I would like to have a different folder dedicated to hold my auxiliary `.tex' file, graphics, and bibliography file.  Then be able to access these files from my current folder.  I am using a Mac if that makes any difference.

My folder structure is as follows:

(for main .tex file):  .../Project/7-21

(for additional files): .../Project/Files/

So my main file is stored in /7-21/ and the files I want to access are in /Files/.

Comment: Use `\input{../../Files/myfile.tex}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it says that the file cannot be found.  I got the file path from 'Get Info' after right-clicking on my file.

Comment: Dox is correct.  So either the file isn't there or you mistyped the path or filename.  Please bear in mind that path and file names are case sensitive and be careful about the use of spaces in file names.

Comment: While Dox's solution should happen to work, it is not [recommended](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169620/8528).  Ideally you fiddle with `TEXINPUTS`.  However, you may also find the [import](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/import) package of value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that your directory structure is as follows.

```
<any folder ignored for the sake of simplicity>/MyFiles/Images/diagram-01.tex
<any folder ignored for the sake of simplicity>/MyFiles/Images/diagram-02.tex
<any folder ignored for the sake of simplicity>/MyFiles/Images/diagram-03.tex
<any folder ignored for the sake of simplicity>/MyFiles/Projects/Report-01/main.tex
<any folder ignored for the sake of simplicity>/MyFiles/Projects/Report-02/main.tex
<any folder ignored for the sake of simplicity>/MyFiles/Projects/Article-01/main.tex
```

`Images` contains diagrams that will be shared among many reports. Each report or article are saved in a separate folder to ease maintenance.

So you can, for example, import the `diagram-01.tex` from the first report's `main.tex` as follows.

```
% my first report
% main.tex
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\input{../../Images/diagram-01.tex}
\end{document}
```

Or if the diagram has been converted to PDF format, you can import it as an image as follows.

```
% my first report
% main.tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../../Images/}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{diagram-01}
\end{document}
```

Here `\graphicspath` declares the path globally. By the way, `\graphicspath` can also be invoked as follows

```
\graphicspath{{../../Images/}{<any path>/}{<any path>/}{<any path>/}<...>}
```

where `<...>` represents that you can add more and more paths, but don't include `<...>` for sure.

### Notes

If the file, i.e., `diagram-01.tex` that you want to import from within the `main.tex` is self-contained input file  which can be compiled then you need to load `docmute` package in the `main.tex` such that `main.tex` will just import the contents sandwiched between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` of the `diagram-01.tex`.

Comment: I can call this approach as my best practice but you may call it as a bombastic approach. :-)

Comment: I am getting some weird stuff happening.  When I try to access a .tex file using input, it doesn't work. (I am actually using another function and putting input inside of this function.)  When I try accessing a graphic using includegraphics+input, it doesn't work.  When I use includegraphics and just put in the file path, it inserts the graphic, but also prints out the file path onto the screen.  Does using graphicspath apply only to this main .tex file or to every other .tex file as well?  I am not sure about how a global variable is defined in LaTeX.

Comment: @bill999: Please first make sure your path does not contain any spaces.

Comment: Good point. I looked and it does, in fact, have spaces.  Is there anything to be done other than actually changing the folder and/or file names to remove the spaces?

Comment: @bill999: You can enclose the path with double quotes, e.g., `"<your path>"`. But having spaces invites unnecessary problems.

Comment: @bill999: Is your file to input self-contained or compilable? If yes, then you need to load `docmute` package in your `main.tex` to extract the body of the file to input.

Comment: 1. I tried the quotes and they didn't help.  They are the " quotes and not the `` '' quotes, correct?  Note that my filename does not contain spaces - only the folder names.

Comment: 2. I can successfully use my additional .tex file if it is loaded into the same folder as `main.tex`.  So I don't think `docmute` is necessary.

Comment: @bill999: OK. Then you must not use `spaces` in folder name to remove complexity. I will update my answer about the quotes later.

Comment: Nothing would work.  It's not a good idea to change my files at this point because other things are hard coded to use them.  Anyway, I was able to just use relative file paths without needing to use `input`.  This was simple and it works perfectly.  Thanks for all of the help.  In the future, knowing about the problem with the spaces in file names and folders should prove to be beneficial.

Comment: @bill999: How do you import a file from with an input file with relative path and without `input`?

Comment: You're right - I do still need to use `input`. See the longer clarification in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that ultimately worked for me was to simply use relative file paths.

So, using the file path in my original answer, to access `tab1.tex` in `/files`, I would just do:

```
../files/tab1.tex
```

(This works with `input` and `includegraphics`.

Also, as is seen elsewhere in this question, how to use absolute file paths where folders contain spaces is still unanswered (although one could just remove the spaces in the actual file paths).  But this is unnecessary for my application as the relative file paths does just fine.

Comment: I don't understand how you can import an external file without `\input`. It looks like a magic.

Comment: Regardless of relative paths or absolute paths, you need to enclose the paths containing spaces.

Comment: I was wrong - I still do need to include `input`.  I misunderstood something.  I am actually a different function (other than `input`) to access my `.tex` file.  I was trying to nest `input` inside of this other function, which is the wrong thing to do.  Anyway, using the relative file position works with `input` and `includegraphics`.  Sorry for the confusion and thanks for pointing my error out to me.  I am new at this kind of stuff and this is helping me gain a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Luckily my relative path contains no spaces.