# How to input file with relative paths within

Tags: emacs, paths, lilypond

In most of my work, I use a specific .tex ("main".tex) file with a preamble and `\begin`- and `\end{document}`. In the document I use `\input{...}` to another .tex file, with no preamble. Let's say "main".tex is located in H:.

My problem is, that when I use a music notation system called "Lilypond", it generates a .tex file with relative paths to pictures. Let's say it's called "lilypond".tex and is located in H:/lilypond/.

When "lilypond".tex is included in my "main".tex file, I get an error because the pictures cannot be located: The compiler searches in H:, because the paths in "lilypond".tex are relative.

How can I avoid this problem, without having to manually edit my "main".tex according to every specific file I might include?

I use Emacs, and have thought of making a macro to run through the "lilypond".tex-file and edit paths, but it might be a little inconvenient.

Comment: just make sure H:lilypond is in your TEXINPUTS path and it should just work.,

Comment: Hi! 

I hadn't thought about that, but I imagine, that I would have to add individual paths to all my lilypond-files, since the pictures is in a folder with each lilypond-file? If H:/lilypond/mozart/mozart.tex and H:/lilypond/beethoven/beethoven.tex both should be able to be compiled, I guess I would have to add both "H:/lilypond/mozart" and "H:/lilypond/beethoven" to TEXTINPUTS?

Comment: No, the relative paths should work should work and in anycase you can add h:/lilypond// where the // denotes all directories below there

Comment: I have made TEXINPUTS as an enviromental variable for my user in Windows 7. I have added a path to the folder, where my lilypond-files are in, but not specified sub-folders (like so, H:\lilypond//). I am still getting the error.

Comment: \input etc. uses Unix files notation.  Use / instead of \.

Comment: See also: [external files - Relative paths for \input and building from different directories - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153751/relative-paths-for-input-and-building-from-different-directories/666389#666389)

Answer (score 1):

in your main file write

```
\graphicspath{{H:/lilypond/}}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I have edited my question because I were not precise enough. I am looking for a solution that avoids editing "main".tex from time to time. My lilypond-files are in various places, and I would have to do a manuel edit of "main".tex according to every lilypond-compilation.

Comment: @simon why don't you use this command in the `input`'d files, then? untested, but i think it'd work.