# Getting xkeyval errors with the 2017 ACM document template

Tags: document-classes, acm, xkeyval

In December of last year, the ACM published an overhaul of the LaTeX document template:

[2017 ACM Master Article Template](http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template)

so, I'm trying to migrate a conference paper of mine from "SIG-ALTERNATE.CLS - VERSION 2.8" to this new template, and even though I seem to be issuing the correct documentclass command:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{include/acmart}
```

just like in the sample conference paper, and yet - I get:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `format' undefined in families `include/acmart.cls'.

...

! Package xkeyval Error: `screen' undefined in families `include/acmart.cls'.
```

and so on. Why is that?

**Note:** If this isn't a well-known/easy-to-identify issue I'll try to extract an M(not)WE from the paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the document class file cannot be placed and loaded from a subdirectory. So if I write:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{include/acmart}
```

I get the errors, but if I pull it up to the same directory as the `.tex` file, and write:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
```

then it's fine. Phhh, annoying. With the olders ACM document class (`sig-alternatate` v2.8) it used to be possible to load the class for a subdirectory this way.

Comment: it is _always_ wrong to  put a filepath into `\documentclass` just as it is wrong to use `\documentclass{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls}` rather than `\documentclass{article}`  you don't have to put the class file in the same directory as the document, just anywhere in the input path.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: (1) I don't accept the analogy (2) Don't see what's wrong with either (3) Can I add relative entries to the input path from within the document? I've read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169620/5640) answer of yours, but I think it's unreasonable to require setting environment variables for that.

Comment: It's not an analogy it is exactly the same issue. _by design_ `\documentclass` takes a class name not a filename or filepath, if (as recommended) the class uses `\ProvidesClass{classname}` then you would get a warning if the argument to `\documentclass` is not identical. there is no need to set additional environment variables tex distributions (almost?) always set a default directory for local files in the input path such as `~/texmf/tex/latex`