# Specify additional include directories within a tex file

Tags: bibliographies, document-classes, include, paths, styles

I want my document to use class files, style files or bibliography style files located in some subdirectory of my TeX document's directory. Sometimes I can sorta-kinda- use, say,

```
\documentclass{include/myclass}
```

and just get a warning. But often even this [does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364311/5640).

What I would really like to do is specify additional include directories - preferably from within the TeX file itself. Is this possible?

Comment: @TobiBS: Yes, I even marked it as a dupe, but my reputation is not high enough.

Comment: I just left a comment (and a vote:-) on the "other" answer at the duplicated question.