# File paths not relative to main.tex but relative to subfile

Tags: input, paths

I am looking for a way, if possible, of specifying file paths not relative to the main document but to the subdocument in which they are contained. As background:

I am writing my thesis chapter by chapter. I have written each chapter as an independent document, edited it, and now want to combine all chapters into one document. Each chapter document is structured to have a `main.tex` which contains the preamble, the `\begin{document}`, etc. The actual text is contained in a file called `toc.tex` which contains the section structuring of each chapter and in turn imports the documents containing each section. So `main.tex` looks something like this:

```
PREAMBLE
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\input{toc.tex}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

each `toc.tex` looks something like the following:

```
\section{A}
\input{./Content/A.tex}
\section{B}
\input{./Content/B.tex}
```

This means that I can compile each chapter individually. My plan was now to compile the overall thesis by using a `main_thesis.tex` which looks something as follows:

```
PREAMBLE
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\input{toc_thesis.tex}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where the file `toc_thesis.tex` looks as follows:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{./chapters/Introduction/toc.tex}
\chapter{Body}
\input{./chapters/Body/toc.tex}
```

My folder structure would thus looks along the following lines:

```
thesis
   chapters
      Introduction
         Content
         Figures
      Body
         Content
         Figures
```

When I now compile `main_thesis.tex` I get an error message saying `` File `./Content/intro.tex' not found. \input{./Content/intro.tex} ``, i.e. the file `toc.tex` in the `Introduction` chapter can't find the file `intro.tex` which is contained in `./chapters/introduction/Content` as it is looking in `./Content` which doesn't exist.

As far as I understand this is because the paths apparently are always relative to where the main file resides not the inputted subfile (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents#Using_different_paths). My question is, is there anyway of changing this behaviour to get LaTeX to use the paths relative to the input files not the main file? I am using TeXStudio should this be of relevance to the question.

Comment: if the filenames are unique you can just set your TEXINPUTS and use `\input{A}` and it will work from the main doc or from  a chapter, otherwise see the `import` package which is designed to address exactly your problem.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I would prefer one main.tex with the whole preamble and the chappter in separate .tex files.

Comment: You can use the import package. But imho on the long run it is more difficult as you have to handle more than one reference point for file path. When you move the file the pathes are wrong. Its easier with not to many subfolders.

Comment: Also related: [Relative paths for \input and building from different directories](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153751/relative-paths-for-input-and-building-from-different-directories)