# Is there a way in latex to print the location of the file itself like in Word?

Tags: header-footer

Word has the feature to print the path to the very file in e.g. the header or footer. How can I achive this with latex?

So, if the path to my document is  `/home/user/tex/report.tex` then I would like to have the path in the header or footer.

Comment: I believe the [`currfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/currfile) package is what you’re looking for, which originated from a TeX.se question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42417/full-path-of-current-file

Comment: The generated pdf is static, you would need to do that with JavaScript. Which means not many readers would support it.

Comment: I was thinking of the path at compile time, but you are right. Word is able to use the actual path, whereas I was thinking only of the path at the time of compilation. After the pdf is moved, the path would be not correct.

Comment: However, if you think about documenting a certain project, then the path in the pdf might indicate the location of the project folder in the depth of your companies vast network-file-system. So printing the compile-time-path might still be useful.