# How to cite tweets?

Tags: biblatex, biber, chicago-style

Is there a smart way to cite tweets? I'm using the Chicago Manual of Style, and all they say is [this](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Documentation/faq0164.html), which is not really a guide, yet.

Ideally, you'd be able to have a macro where you just put the URL to the tweet in, a la:

```
\tweet{https://twitter.com/Horse_ebooks/status/382466889332445184}
```

... and then got the tweet in a nice box on your page, plus in the bibliography. Not sure if this is possible, even theoretically?

Relevant part of my preamble:

```
   \usepackage[backend=biber,isbn=false,notes]{biblatex-chicago}
```

In the main file, I have:

```
 \bibliography{biblio/biblio.bib}
```

What's the next step? Sorry to be grasping for straws like this, hope someone can help out!

Comment: Tweets are are relatively new version of communication and tend to be volatile (they can be deleted, unless retweeted). I am unsure whether the TeX world have already reacted to this kind of communication in the sense, that there are some `.bib` file fields for tweets.

Comment: You can get pretty close using the `@misc` entry type, with the fields: author, title, date, note, and url.  With some minor tweaking via `\DeclareFieldFormat`, you can match the specification you link to.  I'd still want to use one of `biblatex`'s `\cite` commands, however.

Comment: Well in fact this is not a question about TeX, it's related with the kind of references you can use. And well the Chicago Manual Style doesn't take in account the tweets, I don't know if it does with conversations or another related reference. But when you want to cite ephemeral events such a tweet you must cite `Creator, [title], [tweet], date. Notes.` So you can redefine the style you're using or instead of, create a `@misc` entry in your database with `biblatex`. Perhaps the ISO 690:2010 could be helpful for you.

Comment: I agree with @jon: I'dadd them to a bibtex file under `@misc{...}` and give them an author, title, year and url.

Answer (score 18):

I like your question. Yes, it is possible get the tweet and add to bibliography.

I made a 'code' that allow to cite a tweet. Firstly, I am going to explain the idea, then I will explain the code. (It uses `latex` and `python`)

### The idea

1. It is possible get a tweet using `curl` (the string obtained is `json` format) and  the latex package `download` allow to use curl.
2. For convert format `json` to `bibtex` can be used a little script in `python`, that will obtain a .bib file with the tweet data. (I don't know if latex has some package to do this).
3. finally, It is possible to define a little `driver` for `tweet` entry and some macros to manage the tweets.

### The code

**1. Get the tweet in format `json`**

The `download` package allows you to get a tweet using `curl`. It is used in the following form:

```
\download[filelocalname]{url}
```

`filelocalname` is the name of the file in your computer. And the `url` is the url (json) of the tweet. This is important! In your question you show the example url:

`https://twitter.com/Horse_ebooks/status/382466889332445184`  but in this `url` it is only important the `ìdnumber` of the tweet, which is `382466889332445184`.  The `url` for used with `download` package is:

`https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=idnumber`

i.e. in your example the url is:

`https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=382466889332445184`

Then `\tweetadd` is a macro in latex that receives the `idnumber` and downloads the tweet in json format, and also saves it to disk with the name `idnumber.tweet`.

```
\def\tweetadd#1{\download[#1.tweet]{https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=#1}}
```

**2. Convert the tweet from `json` format to `bibtex` format. (`twitt.py`)**

`Beautiful Soup 4` is necessary. The installation instructions are [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup). Beautiful Soup 4 is used to get the `tweet` text, because in the file obtained with `download` package the tweet is in `html` format and Beautiful Soup 4 allows you to extract the `text` of the tweet and `date`.

The other python packages are standard (`json`, `re` and `os`). `json` decodes the file obtained with the `download` package (latex) and extracts the `author name`, `author url`,  and `url` of the tweet. The other fields (`username`, `date`) are obtained with `re`.

How the python script (`twitt.py`) works is simple. The `script` input is the `directory` where are the files downloaded with the `\download` package and finds all the files with the `.tweet` extension. The `script` handles each file and create a file (.bib) with the bibtex data (a `.bib` file for each `.tweet` file).

The fileds of bibtex used are:

- a. `author` Name of author of tweet.
- b. `title`  The tweet text.
- c. `url`    The tweet url.
- d. `nameaddon`  The username of the author (@...).
- e. `addendum`   The url of the profile of the author.
- f. `date`    The date of the tweet.

The entrykey is `tweet:idnumber`.

Finally, the `script` creates a `.tex` file that contains the `\addbibresource` for each `.bib` file. The name is `tweetsinputbib.tex`.

**3. How run `twitt.py` from latex?**

The script follows the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252957/how-to-execute-shell-script-from-latex) using the `\write18` package. As was said in point 2, the script needs the directory of the `.tweet` files (the same directory of .tex file); for this we use the `\currfile` package (latex). Important! The `\currfile` needs the `-recorder` option when latex is executed. For more information, read [Full path of current file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42417/full-path-of-current-file) .

Then the `definetweets` macro runs the `twitt.py` script. (The script needs to be in the same directory of .tex)

```
\def\definetweets{%
\immediate\write18{python \currfileabsdir/twitt.py \currfileabsdir}
}
```

**4. Other macros**

The `\tweet` macro uses the bib fields and prints the `tweet` text, the `date` and the `username`.

```
\def\tweet#1{%
\par
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\columnwidth}%
\hfill\citetitle{#1}\par
\hfill--\citefield{#1}{nameaddon}, \space\citedate{#1}
\end{minipage}\par}
```

The `\citetweet` prints the tweet citation similarly to the form showed in the link that you reference.

```
\def\citetweet#1{%
In a Twitter post on \citedate{#1}, \citeauthor{#1} \mkbibparens{\citefield{#1}{nameaddon}} 
wrote, \mkbibquote{\citetitle{#1}}}
```

Here two format to the fields are defined: `title` (tweet) and `nameaddon` (username). The first prepends the word 'Tweet' to the title. The second puts the username between parens, and if `hyperref` package is used, attaches a link to the user's Twitter profile.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{tweet}{Tweet:\space\emph{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{username}{%
    \mkbibparens{%
      \ifhyperref
        {\href{\thefield{addendum}}{#1}}
        {#1}}}`
```

The `tweet` driver is the default `misc` driver of `authoryear` style of biblatex. (without the fields not used).

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{tweet}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \usebibmacro{author}
  \printfield[username]{nameaddon}
  \newunit
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printfield[tweet]{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printdate
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

### The Full files.

1. the `latex` file. Name: `tweetaddon.tex`

---

```
\usepackage{download}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}[2012/05/06]
\RequirePackage{biblatex}

\def\tweetadd#1{\download[#1.tweet]{https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=#1}}

\def\definetweets{%
\immediate\write18{python \currfileabsdir/twitt.py \currfileabsdir}
}

\def\tweet#1{%
\par
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\columnwidth}%
\hfill\citetitle{#1}\par
\hfill--\citefield{#1}{nameaddon}, \space\citedate{#1}
\end{minipage}\par}

\def\citetweet#1{%
In a Twitter post on \citedate{#1}, \citeauthor{#1} \mkbibparens{\citefield{#1}{nameaddon}} wrote, \mkbibquote{\citetitle{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{tweet}{Twitter post:\space\emph{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{username}{%
    \mkbibparens{%
      \ifhyperref
        {\href{\thefield{addendum}}{#1}}
        {#1}}}

%Driver biblatex for tweet
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{tweet}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \usebibmacro{author}
  \printfield[username]{nameaddon}
  \newunit
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printfield[tweet]{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printdate
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

---

2. The `python` file. Name: `twitt.py`

---

```python
import json
import re
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import os

months={'January':'01','February':'02','March':'03','April':'04','May':'05','June':'06','July':'07','August':'08','September':'09','October':'10','November':'11','December':'12'}

def formatday(day):
    if int(day)<10:
        day='0'+day
    return day

def smplncndtex(string):
    chars={'&':'\&','%':'\%','$':'\$','#':'\#','_':'\_','{':'\{','}':'\}'}
    for item in chars:
        string=string.replace(item,chars[item])
    return string

class tweet:
    def __init__(self, directory=None,file=None):
        self.id=file.replace('.tweet','')
        self.file=file
        self.get_tweet_filecontent(directory)
        self.define_tweet()
        self.entrybib=simpleentrybibtex(self).entry

    def get_tweet_filecontent(self,directory):
        with open(os.path.join(directory,self.file)) as file:
            self.filecontent=file.read()

    def define_tweet(self):
        dcfcnt= json.loads(self.filecontent)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(dcfcnt['html'])
        self.tweet=unicode(smplncndtex(soup.find('p').text))  #in note
        self.author=unicode(smplncndtex(dcfcnt['author_name']))   #in author
        self.author_url=dcfcnt['author_url']   #in addendum
        self.url=dcfcnt['url']   #in url
        username =unicode(smplncndtex('@'+re.match('.+twitter.com/(.+)',self.author_url).group(1)))   #in nameaddon
        self.username=username
        all_a=soup.find_all('a')
        for atag in all_a:
            if atag.get('href')==self.url.replace('/statuses/','/status/'):
                match=re.match('(\w+)\s(\d+),\s(\d+)',atag.text)
                #print date_parts
                self.date= '%s-%s-%s' % (match.group(3),months[match.group(1)],formatday(match.group(2)))
                #print self.date

    def save_tweet(self,directory):
        with open(os.path.join(directory,self.id)+'.bib','w') as file:
            file.write(self.entrybib.encode('utf-8'))

class tweets:
    def __init__(self,directory):
        self.directory=directory
        self.tweets=[]
        self.get_tweets()

    def get_tweets(self):
        for file in os.listdir(self.directory):
            if file.endswith(".tweet"):
                a=tweet(self.directory,file)
                self.tweets.append(a)

class simpleentrybibtex:
    def __init__(self,ctt,entryname='tweet'):
        self.entry='@%s{tweet:%s,author={%s},title={{%s}},url={%s},nameaddon={{%s}},addendum={%s},date={%s}}' % (entryname,ctt.id,ctt.author,ctt.tweet, ctt.url, ctt.username, ctt.author_url, ctt.date)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) ==1:
        print 'It is necessary a directory'
    else:
        if os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
            directory=sys.argv[1]
        #directory='/home/carlos/latex/teste/testedownload'
            tw=tweets(directory)
            tex_input=file(os.path.join(directory,'tweetsinputbib.tex'),'w')
            for tweet in tw.tweets:
                tweet.save_tweet(directory)
                tex_input.write('\\addbibresource{%s}\n' % (tweet.id+'.bib'))
        else:
            print '%s is not a directory' % (sys.argv[1])
```

---

The MWE:

I used the `biblatex` package with the `authoryear` style. I think you can also use `biblatex-chicago`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\input{tweetaddon} %below of \usepackage{biblatex}
%add the tweet to use between \input{tweetaddon} and \definetweets 382466889332445184 is the id tweet in twitter, get it from url of the tweet.
\tweetadd{382466889332445184} 
\tweetadd{382467902751784961} 
\definetweets
\input{tweetsinputbib}        %input this file that contain the addresource
\begin{document}
A tweet:
\tweet{tweet:382466889332445184}  
Other tweet:
\tweet{tweet:382467902751784961}

Or cite a tweet in the form of your link.

\citetweet{tweet:382467902751784961}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result

---

[image]

Comment: Instead of Python you could use Lua for the conversion, with the advantage that any (fairly recent) TeX distribution can use it via `texlua`.