# File path at bottom of last page

Tags: header-footer, footnotes

My boss insists that every document I give him must have the file path to that document at the bottom of the last page. No problem with MS Word, but I don't have a clue how to do this in Latex. At the moment, I am putting a footnote at the end of the document to do this. I thought about special footers but I don't know how to change the footer of just the last page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To improve the solution we need to know what class you are using and if one side or two side printing.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\makeatletter

\def\fullpath{\begingroup\everyeof{\noexpand}\@sanitize
  \edef\x{\@@input|"find `pwd` -name \jobname.tex" }%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\zap@space\x\noexpand\@empty}\x}

\def\ps@path{
\def\@oddfoot{\texttt{\fullpath}\hfil\thepage}
\def\@evenfoot{\texttt{\fullpath}\hfil\thepage}
}
\makeatother
\AtEndDocument{\thispagestyle{path}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

**ps:** `\fullpath` command taken from an [@egreg post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42424/14757) and requires `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

Comment: The document class is article. I am using one-sided printing.

Comment: Also, you need to tell us where you want the page number on the last page. You have 3 positions (left, center and right) on header/footer. What you want on those positions?

Comment: I figure centered page number with the file path centered below it.

Comment: @StevenGregory, did you test my code?m Did it work? I guess that it works on Linux since it uses bash commands. Are you using Windows?

Comment: I'm using the Latex provided by Overleaf on a Windows 7 OS. I'm going to try your code now. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: It will not work on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\makeatletter
\def\ps@path{
   \def\@oddfoot{\texttt{text that I want to be here}\hfil\thepage}
   \def\@evenfoot{\texttt{text that I want to be here}\hfil\thepage}
}
\makeatother
\AtEndDocument{\thispagestyle{path}}
\title{how to put text at the bottom of the last page}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Is this an answer or should it be an edit to the question?

Comment: @Christian, It's an answer. It's an answer. More or less, it is what I ended up using.

Comment: It would be great if there would be some words of explanation to the answer. Code-only answers are generally not the best presentation, so your answer would be a better example with some words added, motivating others to do the same.

Comment: @Stefan, But I don't know what the code is doing. I just played with the original solution until it did what I wanted it to do.

Comment: Normally, I delete downvoted answers. But, since this code actually does what I want it to do, I am going to leave it here.