# How to test --jobname compilation option within latex file

Tags: conditionals, compiling, jobname

Due to some commands in my preamble (`\synctex=1`,`\makenomenclature`,`\settocdepth{subsection}`) which are not fully compatible with `--jobname` procedure, I would like to add a test before these three line to detect if `--jobname` is specified at the compilation. Do you know a way to do such test ?

Or maybe you have another way to get my file compiled with and without `--jobname` option...

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. Somewhat related question: [Macro to retrieve the real name of the source file if pdflatex is invoked with -jobname](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31746/macro-to-retrieve-the-real-name-of-the-source-file-if-pdflatex-is-invoked-with)

Comment: @Daniel: It's now possible. See my answer to the question you linked and to my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I should stress that this only works if `\jobname` is not equal to the file name.

The only method I know of is to hard-code you document name in the file. So for instance if your file is named `test.tex` you could do this testing:

```
\def\myjob{test}
\edef\myjob{\meaning\myjob}
\edef\tmpjob{\jobname}
\edef\tmpjob{\meaning\tmpjob}
\ifx\myjob\tmpjob
  \message{My own job: \jobname}
\else
  \message{Other job: \jobname}
\fi
```

before the `\documentclass`. In this way you know whether you use your *regular* jobname or have supplied it. I do not think you can do it automatically, although I might be wrong.

The reason for doing the above `\edef`s is that `\jobname` is a character where `\myjob` is a letter. Therefore you need to transfer them to the same macro, done by the `\edef` and `\meaning`. If in doubt you can do `\message{\meaning}` in each step to see what is done.

Answer (score 4):

The v0.6 of the [`currfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/currfile) can now detect the real main file using the `-recorder` compiler argument. You can test if this name is identical to the jobname using `\ifcurrfile...` and so determine if the jobname was changed:

```
% Compile with: (pdf|xe|lua|)latex -recorder filename
% Needs two runs with MiKTeX, one with TeX Live
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}[2012/05/06]

\ifcurrfile{\themainfile}{\jobname.tex}{%
%or: \ifcurrfilebase{\jobname}{%
    \message{No \string\jobname\space used!}%
}{%
    \message{\string\jobname\space was used!}%
}


\begin{document}
 ...
\end{document}
```