# re-define \ref and \label to include source filename?

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, include

I have a set of documents each with references that look like:

```
\ref{figure1}
```

and so on. This is no problem when building each document separately,but creates many 
duplicate references when using `\include{}` to create a composite document. Is is possible to redefine the `\ref` and `\label` commands to automatically include the source filename in the reference and label. Otherwise, I would have to hand-edit all my source files with new references to solve the duplicate references problem in the composite document. For example, document1.tex would have references like

```
\ref{figure1_document1}
```

and document2.tex would likewise have the following:

```
\ref{figure1_document2}
```

But I would like this to happen *automatically* by re-defining the commands instead of having to hand-edit each of the source files.

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: Related: [Cross-referencing between different files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14364/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed redefine locally (in each included `.tex` file) the `\ref` and `\label` commands. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{filecontents}    
\let\oldref\ref
\let\oldlabel\label

\begin{filecontents}{file1.tex}
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{#1-stuff}}
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1-stuff}}

\begin{equation}\label{eq}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}    
Eq. \ref{eq} 
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{file2.tex}
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\oldref{#1-stuff2}}
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1-stuff2}}

\begin{equation}\label{eq}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}   
Eq. \ref{eq} 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\include{file1}    
\include{file2}

\end{document}
```

In your case you can put the first two lines (which save the original `\ref` and `\label` commands) in your main file, and then put the `\renewcommand` at the beginning of each included file, as I was trying to mimic here using `filecontents`. Here I am giving manually the text to append to each label in the included file. Replacing `stuff` with `\jobname` will not automatically append the name of the included file, because `\jobname` will be the name of the main file, but perhaps it can be patched (Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31746/macro-to-retrieve-the-real-name-of-the-source-file-if-pdflatex-is-invoked-with/54894#54894) can help you).
There are probably cleaner solutions, but this seems to work.