# Tikz externalize not working when jobname is specified for main document

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, currfile

I'm not sure if it's a well known fact or not, but using the tikz externalization library does not work very well if a LaTeX document is compiled with a jobname that is different from the filename of that document.

For example, if the following MWE is compiled using `pdflatex` (note the `-jobname output` parameter), it won't work unless the file is named `output.tex` (for convenience, let's say it's called `main.tex`):

```
%& -jobname=output
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/only named=true}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \tikzsetnextfilename{sample_tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.50]
    \begin{axis}\addplot {x^3};\end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Sample tikz picture.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If compiled without the `-jobname` parameter, it works just fine, whereas with the parameter, I get an error that looks something like this:

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "sample_tikz" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob
{output}\input{output}"' ========

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "sample_tikz" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{ou
tput}\input{output}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'sample_tikz' (exp
ected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:).
```

From the error message, it is also quite obvious what goes wrong. The default externalization system call looks something like this:

```
pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"
```

where the macro `\texsource` is `\edef`'d as

```
\string\def\string\tikzexternalrealjob{\tikzexternal@realjob}\string\input{\tikzexternal@realjob}
```

and `\tikzexternal@realjob` is set based on the value of `\jobname` used when compiling `main.tex`. When `main.tex` is compiled with `-jobname output`, `\texsource` expands into

```
\def\tikzexternalrealjob{output}\input{output}
```

which is problematic, because `main.tex` isn't called `output.tex`.

### A possible solution

I've tried to look at the tikz external source code, and experimented with how to approach this problem.
My reasoning has been that I want the `\texsource` somehow to expand to

```
\def\tikzexternalrealjob{output}\input{main}
```

instead (note that `\tikzexternalrealjob` must still be `\def`'d to the actual `\jobname`, because it's used in the tikz externalization code to decide whether the current job is for the main document or for the externalization of a tikz image).

I was inspired by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31746/macro-to-retrieve-the-real-name-of-the-source-file-if-pdflatex-is-invoked-with) to use the `currfile` package (thanks @martin-scharrer) to retrieve the name `main` automatically.

What I've come up with so far (which seems to work) is the following:

Change the MWE to:

```
%& -jobname=output -recorder
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/only named=true}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\input{externalize-hack.tex} % <---- THIS WAS ADDED

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \tikzsetnextfilename{sample_tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.50]
    \begin{axis}\addplot {x^3};\end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Sample tikz picture.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and let the file `externalize-hack.tex` be defined as the following:

```
\usepackage{currfile-abspath}
\getmainfile

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter

\AtEndDocument{%
  \newwrite\maindeffile%
  \immediate\openout\maindeffile=\jobname.maindef%
  \immediate\write\maindeffile{%
    \noexpand\ifcsname mymainfile\noexpand\endcsname\noexpand\else%
      \noexpand\gdef\noexpand\mymainfile{\mymainfile}%
    \noexpand\fi%
  }%
  \immediate\closeout\maindeffile%
}

\@input{\jobname.maindef}

\ifcsname mymainfile\endcsname%
  \ifx\mymainfile\@empty%
    % Make a second attempt at extracting the real file name
    % (necessary because currfile needs two runs on MiKTeX..)
    \filename@parse{\themainfile}%
    \let\mymainfile\filename@base%
    \ifx\mymainfile\@empty%
      % If still empty, fallback to default behavior
      \def\mymainfile{\tikzexternal@realjob}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
\else%
  % First attempt at extracting real file name
  \filename@parse{\themainfile}%
  \let\mymainfile\filename@base%
\fi%

\xpatchcmd{\tikzexternal@assemble@systemcall}%
  {%
    \edef\texsource{%
      \string\def\string\tikzexternalrealjob{\tikzexternal@realjob}%
      \string\input{\tikzexternal@realjob}%
    }%
  }%
  {%
    \edef\texsource{%
      \string\def\string\tikzexternalrealjob{\tikzexternal@realjob}%
      \string\def\string\mymainfile{\mymainfile}%
      \string\input{\mymainfile}%
    }%
  }%
  {}
  {}

\let\old@tikzexternalize@opt@withname\tikzexternalize@opt@withname%
\def\tikzexternalize@opt@withname[#1]#2{%
  % Suppress externalization as long as \mymainfile is empty
  % (This will only be the case the one or two first compilation runs!)
  \ifx\mymainfile\@empty\else%
    \old@tikzexternalize@opt@withname[#1]{#2}%
  \fi%
}

\makeatother
```

Also note the `-recorder` option that was added, as required by the `currfile` package.

However, to me this hack feels somewhat clumsy. Hence, I would greatly appreciate any input from you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You got that tikz uses `\jobname` to compose the command line that generates external pics. So redefining `\jobname` and at the same time using tikz externalization is too much trouble.

A possible work-around:

- use `\tikzsetfigurename{something}` to set basename for external tikz pictures;
- call `pdflatex` **without** `-jobname output` everytime you change a tikzpicture, so it correctly generates figures;
- with external figures gerenated, you can change everything in your text at will and call `pdflatex -jobname output` because only checksums are computed without need of real jobname.

It worked with my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzsetfigurename{something}

\begin{document}

\tikz \draw (0,0) -- (1,0.5);

\tikz \draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,0.5);

\end{document}
```

with call sequence:

- `pdflatex -shell-escape main` (here figures `somethingN` are generated)
- `pdflatex -shell-escape -jobname output main`